# Div container outside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can you help me? I have a mockup and I want to convert to Bootstrap, but I have a problem with my container element, if on media query 1024px, an element there's on outside div.

This is my code

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-up">
    <div class="container">
      Objectively pursue extensible web services whereas cooperative deliverables. Phosfluorescently mesh optimal alignments and interoperable niche markets. Credibly whiteboard premium technology and orthogonal customer service. Energistically.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[my-code](https://codepen.io/fordg/pen/xrOpEv)

So how to fix its? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify once again. You have a code that needs to be converted to Bootstrap. What's happening? What you want it to happen?

Comment: please clarify your question

Comment: If you mean that the footer doesn't stay on its place just add `position: fixed;` to your `CSS` file in your `.footer` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a `margin` on your `container`

```css
.homepage {
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 0 5%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.page-content {
  padding: 3% 0;
  background: #fcfef3;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -2px #929497;
}
.footer {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 8%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.footer-up {
  background: #e62731;
  padding: 50px 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
}
.container{
  margin: 15px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="homepage">
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="container">
      Energistically cultivate multidisciplinary portals rather than covalent products. Dynamically maintain functionalized technologies with fully tested solutions. Objectively target low-risk high-yield benefits for end-to-end infomediaries. Proactively coordinate visionary initiatives without team driven convergence. Holisticly transform mission-critical resources whereas low-risk high-yield meta-services.

Seamlessly repurpose enabled technology after reliable technologies. Conveniently reinvent 2.0 results vis-a-vis reliable meta-services. Energistically matrix bricks-and-clicks e-tailers after installed base content. Completely reinvent extensive results whereas synergistic relationships. Holisticly aggregate business supply chains rather than frictionless ideas.

Synergistically.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-up">
    <div class="container">
      Objectively pursue extensible web services whereas cooperative deliverables. Phosfluorescently mesh optimal alignments and interoperable niche markets. Credibly whiteboard premium technology and orthogonal customer service. Energistically.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add css part

```
.container {
  margin:20px;
}
```

Working Fiddle

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zvfvm6q/34/)**

```css
.container {
  margin:20px;
}
.homepage {
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 0 5%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.page-content {
  padding: 3% 0;
  background: #fcfef3;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -2px #929497;
}
.footer {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 8%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.footer-up {
  background: #e62731;
  padding: 50px 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="container">
      Energistically cultivate multidisciplinary portals rather than covalent products. Dynamically maintain functionalized technologies with fully tested solutions. Objectively target low-risk high-yield benefits for end-to-end infomediaries. Proactively coordinate visionary initiatives without team driven convergence. Holisticly transform mission-critical resources whereas low-risk high-yield meta-services.

Seamlessly repurpose enabled technology after reliable technologies. Conveniently reinvent 2.0 results vis-a-vis reliable meta-services. Energistically matrix bricks-and-clicks e-tailers after installed base content. Completely reinvent extensive results whereas synergistic relationships. Holisticly aggregate business supply chains rather than frictionless ideas.

Synergistically.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-up">
    <div class="container">
      Objectively pursue extensible web services whereas cooperative deliverables. Phosfluorescently mesh optimal alignments and interoperable niche markets. Credibly whiteboard premium technology and orthogonal customer service. Energistically.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```